# AS3 best way to traverse/find deep nested objects

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function that needs to find and retrieve dep nested objects and would like to know if there is some optimized function to do it. 
In E4X/XML we have functions like contains or descendants. I can´t find anything for native AS3 Objects.

One example of an object is something like this:

```
[56] (Object)#2262
ID = "Story_u1cac"
Story = (Array)#2263
  [0] (Object)#2264
    AppliedNamedGrid = "n"
    AppliedTOCStyle = "n"
    InCopyExportOption = (Array)#2265
      [0] (Object)#2266
        IncludeAllResources = false
        IncludeGraphicProxies = true
    Self = "u1cac"
    StoryPreference = (Array)#2267
      [0] (Object)#2268
        FrameType = "TextFrameType"
        OpticalMarginAlignment = true
        OpticalMarginSize = 12
        StoryDirection = "LeftToRightDirection"
        StoryOrientation = "Horizontal"
    StoryTitle = "$ID/"
    TrackChanges = false
    XMLElement = (Array)#2269
      [0] (Object)#2270
        MarkupTag = "XMLTag/mehr_1_story"
        ParagraphStyleRange = (Array)#2271
          [0] (Object)#2272
            AppliedParagraphStyle = "ParagraphStyle/Lauftexte%3ainterview"
            CharacterStyleRange = (Array)#2273
              [0] (Object)#2274
                AppliedCharacterStyle = "CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]"
                BaselineShift = 4
                Content = (Array)#2275
                  [0] (Object)#2276
                    nodeValue = "p"
```

Any Ideas?

Any Help is more than apreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using the method posted above by Mark Knol I was able to crate a sort of deep Object filter.
Code follows:

```
function filterObj(object:*, filter:String, arr:Array = null):Array {
        if(arr == null) arr = new Array;

        for(var item:* in object) {
            if(object[item] is Array){
                for(var i:int = 0; i < object[item].length; i++){
                    if(item == filter) {
                        arr.push("some property on some deep nested object");
                    }
                    filterObj(object[item][i], filter, arr);
                }
            }else{
                filterObj(object[item], filter, arr);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

with this  method I´m able to traverse any object tree and push all needed properties.
The downside is that if I push Objects, obviously the nested objects will come inside the parents generating an overhead on copies…

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

There are already a lot of deep tracing util classes for as3. Here is a simple snippet, maybe this helps for you:

```
// some testdata object
var testData:Object = {myObject:{yourVar:"level1"},testObject:"root level",anotherObject:{nestedC:{myVar:"level 2"},greatObject:{otherVar:3,nestedD:{anotherVar:"level3"}}}};

function logDeep(object:*, level:uint = 0):String {
    var retval:String = "";
    for(var item:* in object) {
        if (typeof(object[item]) == "object") {
            retval += getTabs(level) + "[" + level + "]: " + item + " (" + typeof(object[item]) + ")\n";
            retval += logDeep(object[item], level + 1);
        } else {
             if (typeof(object[item]) != "string") retval += getTabs(level) + " - " +  item + " : " + object[item] + " (" + typeof(object[item]) + ")\n";
             else retval += getTabs(level) + " - " +  item + " : '" + object[item] + "' (" + typeof(object[item]) + ")\n";
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

function getTabs(level:uint = 0):String {
    var retval:String = "";
    while (level--) retval+= "\t"
    return retval;
}

// output it to trace-window.
trace(logDeep(testData));
```

Comment: Hey Mark! thanks for the snippet! I wanted to extract objects from the main object if they matched certain criteria... I changed your function a little bit and made a filter. I cant post in ths comment so I will post as answer... BTW, I´m a big fan of your work and your blog! thanks for the generators ;)